# is it possible to get rid of IOS photos delete confirmation popup or customise the message

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on iOS app, which moves the gallery images to cloud. While moving we need to delete the gallery photo. When we delete the photo we are getting confirmation popup fro photos library.

Is it possible to disable the popup or customise content of the message?

Comment: Why after moves the gallery images to cloud photos you need to remove photos from gallery ?

Comment: we are saying migrating to cloud, so need to delete

Answer (score 0):

Nope this is an OS popup that is not customizable.
What you can do is like with requesting permissions- create your own custom popup you will show before the OS one to have a better user experience

Comment: so we will show 2 popups in this case. yeah we want to reduce these popups which results in degradation of User experience